# String to Integer when length is unknown

Tags: java

I am running into a parsing issue in attempting to store the constant terms of polynomials as integers, because of the possibility of them being 1-3 digits long in most simplistic cases, and in saving the equations as a string, I am having trouble parsing out the integers from the alpha values and symbols.

I have tried creating something like

```
    int x = eq.indexOf('x');
```

but because the 'x' character is repeated in the string this parsing method isn't effective.

Is there a more effective method of separating numerical and alpha values in a case like this?

Comment: Is there a specific issue that you're facing? Could you provide more details?

Comment: I'm attempting to create an integer value from a string where the numerical value could range from 1-3 digits.

Comment: Questions generally require one or more sentences with an interrogative (eg. how, which, etc...) and a question mark at the end. Example: "How can I parse an integer from a string of digits?"

Comment: [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-). I suggest going through some basic Java tutorials.

Comment: When using Integer.parseInt, you have to create a substring. I edited the question because I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are your friend:

```
private static List<Integer> extractIntegers(String text) {
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(text);
    while (m.find())
        integers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    return integers;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(extractIntegers("5 + 7 * 13"));
System.out.println(extractIntegers("Simon77 told me 2 go 4 icecream"));
```

*Output*

```
[5, 7, 13]
[77, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Off the top of my head what I would do:

I'm going to guess you're trying to parse some string "25x^2 +2x + 35" describing a polynomial. One approach I might try is to start at the first character (i.e. `2`) and move forward in the string keeping track of some internal state:

```
int state = 1;
for(int i=0; i < my_string.length(); i++) {
   char next_char = my_string.charAt(i);

   // ...

}
```

The next state would be a function of the current state and the current character that's read. The set of possible states would be something like:

1. Current character is white space or start of string.
2. Current character is a digit representing a coefficient.
3. Current character is a variable (i.e. 'x').
4. Current character is an exponent character (i.e. '^')
5. Current character is an exponent digit.

Each time you read a NEW character, you will transition to a new state based upon your last state.

- Eg. if you are in state (1) and read a character digit, you transition to state (2) (i.e. you are reading a coefficient)
- Eg. If I'm in state (2) and read a digit, I stay in state (2). I add the character I've read to some accumulating string of digits
- Eg. if you are in state (2) and read the character 'x', you should parse the digits you've accumulated and that's your next coefficient.
- Eg. If you are in state (4) and read a digit, you transition to state (5).

I'd have some `int state` and a series of switch statements/if statements figuring out what I do as a function of: (i) the current state and (ii) the digit I just read.

#### note

Someone may propose something that's far shorter. But at the least, this would be a good programming exercise.